# Notify User of File with No Checked-in Version

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, rest, check-out, check-in

If a user uploads a document to a document library, but then presses the 'X' button to cancel the document, it becomes checked out and nobody can see the document except for the original user - that is by design.

How can I alert the user that it cannot be viewed by anyone?

I have tried SharePoint Designer (SPD), and I have tried REST API's but obviously these solutions can only see items that are checked out to my account.  How can I generate a notification to a user that they have a item with no checked-in version that no one else can see?

Answer (score 0):

following is the manual option.

You can open the 'Library Settings' for that document library and click on the link titled 'Manage files which have no checked in version'. From this view you can see all those files which were doesn't have any checked in version, i.e. the files for which users have decided to cancel out the metadata form.

From this view you can take Owner ship of those individual files and add metadata by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a PowerShell script on your server to look for files with no initial checked-in version, and perform whatever actions are necessary for each file.

```
$webUrl = "https://sharepoint/SiteCollection"
$libraryTitle = "Shared Documents"

Try
{
    $web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
    if($web -ne $null)
    {

        ForEach($list in ($web.Lists | ? {$_ -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPDocumentLibrary]}))
        {

            If($list.Title -eq $libraryTitle)
            {
                Write-Host "Evalating documents in " $list.Title
                # first get checked out files

                $fileIds = @()
                $Count = 0
                Write-Host " Checking for files without a checked in version"
                ForEach($file in $list.CheckedOutFiles)
                {
                    write-Host $file.LeafName
                    $emailSubject = $file.LeafName + " not accessible to other users"
                    $emailBody = "You uploaded " + $file.LeafName + " at " + $file.TimeLastModified + ".  Please go to " + ($web.url + "/" + $list.rootfolder.url) + " to finish entering metadata and Check-in your file."
                    [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::SendEmail($web ,0,0,$file.CheckedOutByEmail,$emailSubject,$emailBody)
                    # to force check-in of these files, uncomment the next several lines
                    #$file.TakeOverCheckOut()  
                    #$doc = $list.getItemById($file.ListitemId)
                    #$itemFile = $doc.File
                    #if($itemFile -ne $null){
                        #$itemFile.CheckIn("Checked In By Administrator for achive")
                        #write-Host " Checked In" -ForeGroundColor Green
                    #}
                  $Count ++
                }
                Write-Host " Found $Count files that have no checked in version"


                $list.Update()
            }
        }
    }
}
Catch
{
     Write-Host ($Error[0].Exception)
}
```